# Any quick way to call a directory using an environment variable in Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

Say I have a user environment variable named p and it's value is the path where I store my projects.

In Command Prompt you can use them to quickly access a particular directory from anywhere on the command line:

```
cd %p%
```

This doesn't work in Powershell, is there anyway to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Environment variables have their own provider:

```
cd $env:p
```

Answer (score 2):

addtional info:
You can also set that environment variable for your session incase you need to change it for some reason during your session

```
$env:p = "C:\MyPath"
```

Or to set it globally if you need to update it

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("p", "C:\MyPath", "User")
```

This would create the user environment variable.